# Store results from a function

Tags: r

There is a need to store results returned from a function call at each iteration of the loop.

```
for (i in 1:x)
{
    datax <- trainingdata[[i]]
    levels(datax$label) <- c(-1, 1)
    train_x<-datax[, -1]
    train_x<-data.matrix(train_x)
    trainy<-datax[, 1]

    s_x<-svm.fs(train_x, y=trainy, fs.method="scad",
                          cross.outer=0, grid.search="discrete",
                          lambda1.set=lambda1.scad, parms.coding="none",
                          show="none", maxIter=1000, inner.val.method="cv",
                          cross.inner=5, seed=seed, verbose=FALSE)
    # Store the result s_x
}
```

The s_x need to be stored along with a name (which is already present in a vector "names").

I have tried the following:

```
s_x_results <- data.frame(x=names, y=data.frame(length(trainingdata)))

for (i in 1:x)
{
    datax <- trainingdata[[i]]
    levels(datax$label) <- c(-1, 1)
    train_x<-datax[, -1]
    train_x<-data.matrix(train_x)
    trainy<-datax[, 1]

    s_x<-svm.fs(train_x, y=trainy, fs.method="scad",
                          cross.outer=0, grid.search="discrete",
                          lambda1.set=lambda1.scad, parms.coding="none",
                          show="none", maxIter=1000, inner.val.method="cv",
                          cross.inner=5, seed=seed, verbose=FALSE)

    s_x_results[i]$y <- s_x
}
```

but I get the error message:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "scad.fix", value = list(classes = c(1L,  : 
replacement has 11 rows, data has 91
```

The final object s_x_results is saved in some file for future correspondence.

Comment: Do you want to store `s_x` seperately in seperate objects for each iteration or combine then in some sort of list?

Comment: I want to store all the results in one object s_x_results. Thanks

Comment: What is the structure of s_x?

Comment: `svm.fs` is from what pacakge? And what is the structure of an element from your training data list (I assume each element is a data.frame - if it is not too many columns posting the output from `dput(head(trainingdata[[1]]))` would be useful for people to reconstruct your data in R. To my mind your obvious problem is that `svm.fs` is outputting a vector of length 11, whilst your results dataframe has 91 rows (you have 91 elements in training data?).  You also have not defined `names` for us in `x=names`. The answers below look pretty good if you turn your loop into a function.

Comment: @SimonO101 svm.fs is from penalizedSVM package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `lapply`

```
myFunc <- function(i) {
    datax <- trainingdata[[i]]
    levels(datax$label) <- c(-1, 1)
    train_x<-datax[, -1]
    train_x<-data.matrix(train_x)
    trainy<-datax[, 1]

    svm.fs(train_x, y=trainy, fs.method="scad",
                cross.outer=0, grid.search="discrete",
                lambda1.set=lambda1.scad, parms.coding="none",
                show="none", maxIter=1000, inner.val.method="cv",
                cross.inner=5, seed=seed, verbose=FALSE)
}

s_x_results <- lapply(1:x, myFunc)

#Access individual results using s_x_results[[1]], s_x_results[[2]] and so on.
```

This should give you list of x dataframes.

PS: Untested function since no sample data is provided.

Comment: Thanks. What about associating name with each result of myFunc?

Comment: @Shahzad It's not clear what exactly you are looking for? Do you want to create an object for each iteration , such that for `i`th iteration an object is created whose name is taken from string in `names[i]`

Comment: No. Its ok now. I have used the following expression to make it work.
names(s_x_results) <- c(names[1:length(s_x_results)]). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try `replicate`

```
 res <- replicate(x,funcall)
```

Comment: Thanks. Please provide some more detail of where to place this expression. How "res" fits in my code?